# I am working on a project containing activities and i want to convert some tabs activities into fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to convert HomeActivity into HomeFragment. As I want to use

```
 changefragment(new HomeFragment());
```

What should I do? Please Suggest

Comment: do you want somebody to do it instead of you?

Comment: @surbhi I can give you the reference link only. This may help you https://www.raywenderlich.com/117838/introduction-to-android-fragments-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the way that the views are instantiated in the activities and shift it to the fragments. My personal preference is to create a new class file for the fragment and name it Fragment, eg. `ListActivity` = `ListFragment`.

Then inside the activity `onCreate` method, you setContentView normally:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
```

Then you need to create an instance of the fragment and inject it into the container that you've created inside your activity_list layout file:

```
ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.activity_list_container, fragment)
                .commit();
```

Treat the fragment similarly to the activity, except instead of using `this` when referring to context, you use `getActivity()`.

Here's an example of what your `activity_list.xml` layout file could look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ListActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/activity_list_container"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```